# Class event fires only one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Table of data with its link:

```
<strong>1</strong> <a href ='index.cgi?reqpage=2&job_category_id=1' class='paginateAdmin' id='nonItPaginate'>nextPage</a> 

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.paginateAdmin').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var post = $(this).attr("href");
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var array = post.split('?');
        $.post(
            'index.cgi',
        array[1],
        function (data, status) {
            switch (id) {
                case "nonItPaginate":
                    $('#nonit').html(data);
                    break;
                case "ItPaginate":
                    $('#it').html(data);
                    break;
                case "govtPaginate":
                    $('#govt').html(data);
                    break;
                default:
            }
        });
    });
});
```

After post request the data consists of link.

Table of data with this link:

```
<strong>2</strong> <a href ='index.cgi?reqpage=3&job_category_id=1' class='paginateAdmin' id='nonItPaginate'>nextPage</a>
```

but when I click the <kbd>nextPage</kbd>, click event is not working. If it works so that I can get the response data has:

Table of data

```
<strong>3</strong> <a href ='index.cgi?reqpage=4&job_category_id=1' class='paginateAdmin' id='nonItPaginate'>nextPage</a>
```

but it is not firing an event.

Comment: can you edit this to add your html?

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` on the third line from the bottom, it should be `});`, but it's currently `);`

Comment: Is elements with class `paginateAdmin` added dynamically?

Comment: for the first time it is loaded by default and the for the next times it loaded from the ajax post responses.

Answer (score 0):

this `$('.paginateAdmin').on('click', function(){})` will bind `click` event only for all existing elements with `paginateAdmin` class. 
You need to use such syntax instead: `$(document).on('click', '.paginateAdmin', function(){...`

Answer (score 0):

solution is

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $(document).on('click','.paginateAdmin',
            function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        var post = $(this).attr("href");
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        var array = post.split('?');

    $.post(
        'index.cgi',
        array[1],
        function(data,status){

           switch(id)
            {
                case "nonItPaginate":

                     $('#nonit').html(data);

                    break;
                case "ItPaginate":

                         $('#it').html(data);
                        break;
                case "govtPaginate":

                     $('#govt').html(data);
                    break;
            default:

                 }


    });

    });
     });
```